# Null Pointer Exception AndroidPlot in Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, graph, androidplot

Hello guys I got a Null Pointer Exception  if I want to open a graph in a fragment.

This is my exception code:

```
Graph.onCreate(Bundle) line: 39 
Graph(Fragment).performCreate(Bundle) line: 1755    
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) line: 868 
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, int, int, boolean) line: 1106  
BackStackRecord.run() line: 690 
FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() line: 1571 
FragmentManagerImpl$1.run() line: 447   
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
Handler.dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95
```

This is my Fragment code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.graph_fragment);
         plot = (XYPlot) getView().findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot3);
            // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
             Number[] series1Numbers = {1, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4,3,5,12,50,10,20};
             Number[] series2Numbers = {4, 6, 3, 8, 2, 100};

             // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
             XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                     Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
                     SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
                     "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series

             // same as above
             XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");

             // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer
             // and configure it from xml:
             LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
             series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
             series1Format.configure(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);

             // add a new series' to the xyplot:
             plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

             // same as above:
             LineAndPointFormatter series2Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
             series2Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
             series2Format.configure(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf2);
             plot.addSeries(series2, series2Format);

             // reduce the number of range labels
             plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(1);

             plot.setDomainStepValue(series1Numbers.length);

             plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);
```

How can I open the graph without the null pointer exception?
Can I load the data in my activity and add them to the Fragment?
Would that change something?
Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override oncreateView and inflate your xml file there. Try this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_fragment, container,
            false);
    //your plot would look like this:
            plot = (XYPlot) view.findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot3);
    return view;
}
```

Its generally a good practice to override onStart method and use the objects on this method.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);
}
```

Comment: @Strik3r have you declared  Number[] series1Numbers = {1, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4,3,5,12,50,10,20};
             Number[] series2Numbers = {4, 6, 3, 8, 2, 100}; as class level variables so that it can be used in onstart

Answer (score 2):

onCreate is called before `onCreateView` and `getView` returns null before `onCreateView` is completed, making your app crashing at

```
 plot = (XYPlot) getView().findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot3);
```

You can override `onViewCreated` and move all the initialization staff inside that method

Comment: how should it look like? Should I paste the code to the onCreateView method?

Comment: thank yout it works:) but why are there no values in the graph?